# How to select the ALL passed parameter values inside the stored procedure in SQL like SQL Trace

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How to select all parameters and values passed to the stored procedure as like in SQL Trace, inside the procedure using any @@ function without any customization.
For Example I have a stored procedure like

```
CREATE PROC test_Procedure
      @ln varchar(25) = '',
      @fn varchar(25) = '',
      @dob datetime = NULL,
            @id INT = 0
AS
BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM tb_users
            WHERE ln= @ln
            AND  fn = @fn
            AND  dob = @dob
            AND Id = @id

------------ SELECT @@
END
```

If I called the procedure like

```
EXEC     [dbo].test_Procedure @ln = N'a',@fn = NULL,@dob = NULL,@id  = 1
```

I need to select this exact string inside the procedure using any built in function or user defined function .

Comment: i work with stored procs pretty much daily for the last 10 years, and I have no idea what you are asking!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to output debugging style info you could use something like this;

```
SELECT CONCAT('test_Procedure @ln = ', @ln, ', @fn = ', @fn, ', @dob = ', @dob, ', @id = ', @id)
```